# ListPlot — using a string as a tick label

Tags: plotting

I would like to rename some results in a list plot on the x-axis with a description. I though I could do it with `Ticks`, but it didn't work. Can someone please help me?

Here the code:

```
parameters = 
  {{1, 0.910299}, {2, 0.98625}, {3, 1.09987}, {4, 0.98742}, {5, 0.935837}};
seplus = 
  {{1, 0.910299 + (2*0.0426755)}, {2, 0.98625 + (2*0.0441949)}, 
   {3, 1.09987 + (2*0.0494856)}, {4, 0.98742 + (2*0.0442918)}, 
   {5, 0.935837 + (2*0.0418519)}}; 
seminus = 
  {{1, 0.910299 - (2*0.0426755)}, {2, 0.98625 - (2*0.0441949)}, 
   {3, 1.09987 - (2*0.0494856)}, {4, 0.98742 - (2*0.0442918)}, 
   {5, 0.935837 - (2*0.0418519)}}; 
plotindex = 
  ListPlot[parameters, 
    Frame -> True, 
    Joined -> False, 
    AxesOrigin -> {1, 1}, 
    Ticks -> 
      {Automatic, 
       {{1, "Text1"}, {2, "Text2"}, {3, "Text3"}, {4,"Text4"}, {5, "Text5"}}, 
       Automatic}, 
    PlotStyle -> Gray];
plotseplus = 
   ListPlot[{seplus, seminus}, 
     Frame -> True, 
     Joined -> False, 
     Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
     AxesOrigin -> {1, 1}, 
     Ticks -> 
       {Automatic, 
        {{1, "Text1"}, {2, "Text2"}, {3, "Text3"}, {4,"Text4"}, {5, "Text5"}}, 
        Automatic}, 
     PlotStyle -> Black]; 
tailindices = Show[plotseplus, plotindex]
```

Comment: You're using `Frame->True`, so see `FrameTicks`.

Comment: Try `FrameTicks -> {{Automatic,   Automatic}, {{{1, "Text1"}, {2, "Text2"}, {3, "Text3"}, {4,   "Text4"}, {5, "Text5"}}, Automatic}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to use `FrameTicks`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
tick[s_String] := Rotate[s, 90 Degree];
plotseplus = ListPlot[{seplus, seminus},
   Frame -> True,
   Joined -> False,
   Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
   AxesOrigin -> {1, 1},
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic,None}, 
        {{{1, tick@"Text1"}, {2, tick@"Text2"}, {3,tick@"Text3"}, 
         {4, tick@"Text4"}, {5, tick@"Text5"}}, None}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Black];
```